# Incorrect write EXIF metadata to image

Tags: ios, swift, image, metadata, exif

**I try put few exif parameters to image, but only few of them are visible.**

When check information about exifDictionary all parametras has a value
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OirK.png

But when check this file in exiftool, BodySerialNumber are valid, FileSource is incorrect value, and DateTimeOriginal is not visible, really don't understand what's going on
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf4l4.png

> **This is my code, where i try to save meta to file**

```
static func encodeImage(at url: URL, file: File, completionHandler: ((URL?) -> Void)?) {
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as URL
    let filePath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(UUID().uuidString)\(file.fileExtension ?? ".jpg")")

    guard let data = NSData(contentsOf: url),
          let src = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data, nil),
          let uti = CGImageSourceGetType(src),
          let cfPath = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(nil, filePath.path as CFString, CFURLPathStyle.cfurlposixPathStyle, false),
          let dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(cfPath, uti, 1, nil)
    else {
        completionHandler?(nil)
        return
    }

    let exifProperties = [
        kCGImagePropertyExifBodySerialNumber as String: file.device ?? "0",
        kCGImagePropertyExifFileSource as String: file.deviceUrl ?? file.path,
        kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal as String: "\(file.createdAt.milliseconds)"
    ] as CFDictionary
    
    let exifDictionary = [
        kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary as String: exifProperties
    ] as CFDictionary
    
    CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(dest, src, .zero, exifDictionary)
    if CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest) {
        completionHandler?(filePath)
    } else {
        completionHandler?(nil)
    }
}
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: FileSource is not meant to be a file name but rather the type of input device

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thx, maybe you know what key I must use to write original path to file ?

Comment: Try running this exiftool command on the file:  
`exiftool -v2 file.png`   
This will give you a breakdown of where the data is located in the file.  What you want to check for to see if the EXIF data is stored in the `PNG eXIf` block or in a `PNG zTXt` block.  If it's in a `zTXt` block, then you're writing non-standard EXIF.  Before mid-2017, there was no official EXIF standard for PNGs but some programs wrote EXIF data in a `zTXt` as a work-around.

Comment: The exiftool `Filepath` isn't an embedded tag.  It's the absolute path of the file as taken from the underlying file system.  If you check the [exiftool Extra tags page](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Extra.html), you'll see that it is listed as a "System" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki
The main problem because in `Java / Kotlin`, they can programatically write what they want in meta keys, maybe they use another version of exif, I really don't know about it, but in `Swift` you can use special format to key. All keys described in https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif.html

And when I try to write `String` in `kCGImagePropertyExifFileSource` field I have 0, because this field must outcome integer value 1 ... 3

The same problem with `kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal` here not only a `String` must be written, but also a special format `YYYY: MM: DD HH: MM: SS`, other formats cannot be written into this field !!!

**What I mean, read about field formats and types!)**